# Analysis of kd-tree, how is the vertical line L's intersect areas equivalent to sqrt(N)?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

I'm trying to understand how the number of intersected areas by a vertical line in a KD-tree is equivalent to sqrt(n)

If you draw a balanced KD-tree with 7 nodes.
[image]

And then draw a vertical line l.

[image]

The number of areas this line intersects should be equivalent to sqrt(N) where N is amount of nodes. (7)

When I count the areas the vertical line L intersects I get 5. But sqrt(7) = 2,6 not even close.

Both sources get to the recurrence:

[image]

Which solves to O(sqrt(N)).

What am I doing wrong?

Sources:

[Source 1](https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/D42/%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%AC%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B5%CF%82/3a.tree.pdf)

[Source 2](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/cis5930/kdtree.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The claim that the number of such intersections is $O(\sqrt{n})$ does not mean it is $\sqrt{n}$; you are ignoring the hidden constant.

I don't know whether the claim is true.  Slides are not a good source for this material.  Reading and working through and understanding the analysis in Section 3.2 of the paper you linked would be the best way to resolve this.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at section 3.2, and it states "any vertical line intersects O(√n) regions in KD-tree" on page 11. I forgot about the constant in the big Oh notation. In my case, if I do sqrt(7) * 2 = 5.29, this shows that its a correct upper bound when N = 7, but can I then assume that there exists a constant C where O(sqrt(n)) will always be the upper bound for Q(√n)?